# How do you replace missing even values In a variable having 1 to 100 values?

Tags: sas

dataset looks like this

variable
1
.
3
.
5
.
7
.
9

How do you replace missing even values with the correct one
and resulting data should appear as
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Comment: please don't insert assignments here without trying, coz it sounds `ODD` for this site `EVEN` if the question is about programming

Comment: You don't provide enough information to know how to know how '2' goes between '1' and '3'.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean that the data looks like this:?

```
var
---
1
.
3
.
etc
```

and you want the ones in between to be one more than the one before? if so ...

```
data one;
  input var;
datalines;
1
.
3
.
5
;
run;

data two (drop=prev_var);
  set one;
  retain prev_var;
  if missing(var) then do;
    var = prev_var + 1;
  end;
  prev_var=var;
run;

proc print data = two noobs; run;
```